# Unable to play most video files on ubuntu Groovy Gorilla

Tags: 20.10, video-player, smplayer

I updated my ubuntu recently, and ever since I've done that I'm no longer able to play most of my video files with the default purple video app of ubuntu. It's so annoying that I constantly have to switsch to another application like SMPlayer and so on. I have no idea why this happens. Here is what I get shown when I click on a video to play:

[image]

When I click on "Find in ubuntu software" I'm also shown nothing. I wonder why this should happen in a newer version of ubuntu since it was all fine with the previous, I've always stuck to the defaults!
I'd appreciate it if somebody could help me fix this or at least figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Looks lije you are missing the multimedia codecs. [This reference](https://linuxhint.com/install_multimedia_codecs_ubuntu/) shows you how to install them.

Comment: @24601 Thanks for making the pic visible! I'm not allowed to do it yet due to my low reputation :)

Comment: Whilst my reference refers to 20.04 it will in all probablility be the same issie with 20.10

Comment: Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: Nope, it still does not work :(( @24601

Comment: I found that the GNOME deafult `Videos` aka `Totem`  works for me downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Center.